# String formatting in Python version earlier than 2.6

Tags: python, format

When I run the following code in Python 2.5.2:

```
for x in range(1, 11):
    print '{0:2d} {1:3d} {2:4d}'.format(x, x*x, x*x*x)
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#9>", line 2, in <module>
    print '{0:2d} {1:3d} {2:4d}'.format(x, x*x, x*x*x)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'format'
```

I don't understand the problem.

From `dir('hello')` there is no `format` attribute.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 48):

The `str.format` method was [introduced in Python 3.0, and backported](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/2.6.html#pep-3101-advanced-string-formatting) to Python 2.6 and later.

Answer (score 38):

Your example code seems to be written for Python 2.6 or later, where [the `str.format` method was introduced](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/2.6.html#pep-3101-advanced-string-formatting).

For Python versions below 2.6, use [the % operator](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) to interpolate a sequence of values into a format string:

```
for x in range(1, 11):
    print '%2d %3d %4d' % (x, x*x, x*x*x)
```

---

You should also be aware that this operator can interpolate by *name* from a mapping, instead of just positional arguments:

```
>>> "%(foo)s %(bar)d" % {'bar': 42, 'foo': "spam", 'baz': None}
'spam 42'
```

In combination with the fact that the built-in vars() function returns attributes of a namespace as a mapping, this can be very handy:

```
>>> bar = 42
>>> foo = "spam"
>>> baz = None
>>> "%(foo)s %(bar)d" % vars()
'spam 42'
```

Comment: This is a good description, but it doesn't describe how to implement the formatting in the presented example.

Comment: @JasonR.Coombs: thanks, I have the code corresponding to the presented example now as the first in the answer.

Answer (score 8):

I believe that is a Python 3.0 feature, although it is in version 2.6. But if you have a version of Python below that, that type of string formatting will not work.

If you are trying to print formatted strings in general, use Python's printf-style syntax through the `%` operator. For example:

```
print '%.2f' % some_var
```

Answer (score 7):

Which Python version do you use?

**Edit**
For Python 2.5, use `"x = %s" % (x)` (for printing strings)

If you want to print other types, [see here](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting).

Answer (score 7):

*Although the existing answers describe the causes and point in the direction of a fix, none of them actually provide a solution that accomplishes what the question asks.*

You have two options to solve the problem. The first is to upgrade to Python 2.6 or greater, which supports the [format string construct](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string-formatting).

The second option is to use the [older string formatting with the % operator](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations). The equivalent code of what you've presented would be as follows.

```
for x in range(1,11):
  print '%2d %3d %4d' % (x, x*x, x*x*x)
```

This code snipped produces exactly the same output in Python 2.5 as your example code produces in Python 2.6 and greater.

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

```
print "test some char {} and also number {}".format('a', 123)
```

result:

> test some char a and also number 123

Comment: If you downgrade, at least explain why it's not correct