# How to print an incremented int identifier in a string in Python

Tags: python, printing, string-concatenation

In Java, If I want to print an incremented int variable, I can do it as:

```
int age = scn.nextInt();
System.out.println("You are " + age + " years old going on " + (age+1));
```

**Output:**

```
21
You are 21 years old going on 22
```

Is it possible to do the same in Python?

I tried the following, and none of them work.

```
age = input("How old are you?")
print("You are " + age + " years old going on " + str(age+1))
print("You are " + age + " years old going on {}".format(age+1))
print("You are " , age , " years old going on " , str(age+1))
print("You are %d years old going on %d" %(age, age+1))
print("You are " + str(age) + " years old going on " + str(age+1))
```

I have already tried the solutions provided in these links:

[Print Combining Strings and Numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12018992/print-combining-strings-and-numbers)

[Concatenating string and integer in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11559062/concatenating-string-and-integer-in-python)

[Converting integer to string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961632/converting-integer-to-string-in-python)

[TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13654168/typeerror-cant-convert-int-object-to-str-implicitly)

Comment: input gives you a string. You have to convert it to an integer before you add 1: `age = int(input...`

Comment: **Even though an answer has already been accepted, please feel free to contribute answers here. I will still accept/upvote your good and informative solution.**

Comment: "I tried the following, and none of them work." This is because `age` is a **string, not an integer**. To solve the problem correctly, it is necessary to read an integer, use integers to do the math, and **then** convert back to string for concatenation (or format back into the string). This question needs more focus, and should be deleted; there are really two problems in one, and it results from a failure to [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) or produce a [mre].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the input to an int :

```
>>> age = int(input("How old are you?"))
```

And then the following work :

```
print("You are " , age , " years old going on " , str(age+1))
print("You are %d years old going on %d" %(age, age+1))
print("You are " + str(age) + " years old going on " + str(age+1))
```

Comment: I see, I was mislead by the error message from Python. All the while I thought it complains that `int` cannot be converted to `string` and in actual fact, it can't convert `string` to `int` to do the increment.

Comment: Also `print("You are {} years old going on {}".format(age,age+1)) for completeness.

Comment: Just to add, try to stick with the second print format, because that way you are in charge of formatting your print statement properly. Better, experiment with different format like %f, %s, %r and other. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

In all `print` cases you're trying to add a `str` to an `int` and the error tells you that that form of implicit convesion is not possible:

```
'21' +1

TypeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-60-3473188b220d> in <module>()
----> 1 '21' +1

TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

`input` behaves differently in `Python 3.x` in that it doesn't evaluate the input but just returns it as a `str`.

Wrap the input result in an `int` call to get it to work by explicitly casting the string to an `int`:

```
age = int(input("How old are you?"))
```

The only caveat here is if you don't supply a value during input that's capable of being transformed to an `int` you'll get a `ValueError`. In this case you should create a `while` loop that will `try` and transform input to `int` and `break` on success (i.e no Exception raised).

Comment: Can I say that Python does not do any auto parsing from int to string like Java? Hence I always have to perform an explicit parsing?

Comment: @user3437460 yes, you have to be explicit in cases like `input`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to change it into `int` it is already.

```
>>> age = input("age")
age21
>>> age
21
>>> type(age)
<type 'int'>
```

As you are concatenating string and integer you are not getting the result

**Try This**:

```
print("You are {} years old going on {}".format(age,age+1))
```

Comment: I still need to do `age = int(input("How old are you?"))` first.

Comment: In my case, it shows `'21'` instead of `21`. In my case `age` is still of type `str`.

Comment: @user3437460 That is a difference between Python 2 and 3. In Python 3: `input` is the equivalent of Python 2 `raw_input` - they return strings. However, `input` in Python 2 is the same as doing `eval(input())` in Python 3.