# how can i put variable with integer type in print?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, function, integer

```
    a = int(input('enter a number :'))
    b = i+1
    print('your number + 1 = {b}')
```

> I get back the following:

```
    enter a number :
```

> after i enter a number print following text

```
    your number + 1 = {b}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concatenating string and integer in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11559062/concatenating-string-and-integer-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

You want a [f-string](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) for formatted string:

```py
a = int(input('enter a number :'))
b = i+1
print(f'your number + 1 = {b}')
```

which needs to be prefixed with an `f` before the quote marks (single or double).