# Python: Connect 4 Grid

Tags: python, join, grid

I'm making a connect 4 game and i don't know how to use the join() function to make the grid. The grid is suppose to have 7 columns and 6 rows. I only know how to write it this way....

```
print "   1   2   3   4    5   6   7"
print  board[0][0] + " | " + board[0][1] + " | " + board[0][2] + " | " + board[0][3] + " | " + board[0][4] + " | " + board[0][5] + " | " + board[0][6] + " | " + board[0][7]
print "  ---+---+---+---+---+---+---"
print  board[1][0] + " | " + board[1][1] + " | " + board[1][2] + " | " + board[1][3] + " | " + board[1][4] + " | " + board[1][5] + " | " + board [1][6] + " | " + board [1][7]  
print "  ---+---+---+---+---+---+---+"
print  board[2][0] + " | " + board[2][1] + " | " + board[2][2] + " | " + board[2][3] + " | " + board [2][4] + " | " + board [2][5] + " | " + board [2][6] + " | " + board [2][7]
print "  ---+---+---+---+---+---+---+"
print  board[3][0] + " | " + board[3][1] + " | " + board[3][2] + " | " + board[3][3] + " | " + board [3][4] + " | " + board [3][5] + " | " + board [3][6] + " | " + board [3][7]
print "  ---+---+---+---+---+---+---+"
print  board[4][0] + " | " + board[4][1] + " | " + board[4][2] + " | " + board[4][3] + " | " + board [4][4] + " | " + board [4][5] + " | " + board [4][6] + " | " + board [4][7]
print "  ---+---+---+---+---+---+---+"
print  board[5][0] + " | " + board[5][1] + " | " + board[5][2] + " | " + board[5][3] + " | " + board [5][4] + " | " + board [5][5] + " | " + board [5][6] + " | " + board [5][7]
print
```

Comment: So, to clear things up, do you want to know how to use the `join()` function, how to make the board, both, or how to make the board assuming you HAVE to use `join()`?

Comment: how to make the board assuming you HAVE to use join()

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
# generate 2D array of `X` so the code will run
n,m = 6,7
board = [["X" for i in range(m)] for j in range(n)]

print(" "*3 + (" "*3).join(["{}".format(i) for i in range(1,m+1)]))
for j,bb in enumerate(board):
    print("{}: ".format(j+1)  + " | ".join(bb))
```

It will print:

```
   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
1: X | X | X | X | X | X | X
2: X | X | X | X | X | X | X
3: X | X | X | X | X | X | X
4: X | X | X | X | X | X | X
5: X | X | X | X | X | X | X
6: X | X | X | X | X | X | X
```

Comment: how you do make the column number start with 1 instead of 0?

Comment: i got AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'format'

Comment: @user3161743: Are you using an old python <2.7? Look at e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/q/792721/1879010

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
board = [['X' for i in range(8)] for row in range(8)]
```

Two prints:

```
print '   ' + '   '.join(map(str, range(1, 9)))
print '\n'.join('{0}: '.format(i+1) + ' | '.join(row) for i, row in enumerate(board))
```

Outputs:

```
   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
1: X | X | X | X | X | X | X | X
2: X | X | X | X | X | X | X | X
3: X | X | X | X | X | X | X | X
4: X | X | X | X | X | X | X | X
5: X | X | X | X | X | X | X | X
6: X | X | X | X | X | X | X | X
7: X | X | X | X | X | X | X | X
8: X | X | X | X | X | X | X | X
```

Breaking it down into a more readable for-loop, for clarity:

```
for i, row in enumerate(board):
    actual_board = ' | '.join(row)
    row_text = '{0}: '.format(i+1)  #i+1 to start with 1 instead of 0
    print row_text + actual_board
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x,y=6,7
print '   ' + '   '.join(map(str,range(1,y+1)))

for i in range(1,x+1):
    print "%d: "%i + ' | '.join(board[i-1])
    if i != x:
        print '  '+'+'.join(['---']*y)
```

This prints exactly the same result as your code.